# Google Cloud Storage End Point Error in List Method

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

Everything works fine I just get the error (given below) in list method when there are more than 0 elements.

This is the Room End Point Class

```
@Api(name = "roomendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "rafia.com", ownerName = "rafia.com", packagePath = "time_table.server.model"))
public class RoomEndpoint {

/**
 * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
 * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
 *
 * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
 * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "listRoom")
public CollectionResponse<Room> listRoom(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<Room> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getEntityManager();
        Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Room as Room");
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<Room>) query.getResultList();
        cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

        // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
        // for lazy fetch.
        for (Room obj : execute)
            ;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<Room> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
   }
 }
```

This is the original room Class from where I generated End Point using eclipse google plugin by righ click-> generate End point

```
package com.rafia.time_table.server.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Room {
@Id
private long id;
private String roomId;
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getRoomId() {
    return roomId;
}
public void setRoomId(String roomId) {
    this.roomId = roomId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}
public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
private String name;
private String location;
private int capacity;

}
```

When I Test the api using api explorer everything works fine just the list method gives this error. I have spent a lot of time please guide.

**Error HERE**

```
Jan 03, 2015 3:51:06 AM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.fetchLongField(QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.java:74)
    at org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityUtils.getApplicationIdentityForResultSetRow(IdentityUtils.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1011)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$LazyAbstractListIterator.computeNext(LazyResult.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:131)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$AbstractListIterator.hasNext(LazyResult.java:183)
    at com.rafia.time_table.server.model.RoomEndpoint.listRoom(RoomEndpoint.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use long as the primary key type. I'd suggest using Long instead. You can read about the acceptable key types [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys).